# How to record and play back audio using media.newRecording

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've created 3 squares. I want the first square to record and save the recording. Second square to stop the recording. Third square to get the recording and play it back.

I'm able to get a response when I use the app on my computer, but the results aren't very clear(I don't have a mic). When I test on my phone I don't get any response.

How to make this app work?

```
function startRecording ()
print( "startRec tap" )
recordPath = system.pathForFile( "recordings.wav", system.DocumentsDirectory )
recording = media.newRecording( recordPath )
recording:startTuner( )
recording:startRecording( )

proof1 = display.newText( "proof1", 80, 300,nil , 20 )  
end


function stopRecording(  )
print( "stopRec tap" )
proof2 = display.newText( "proof2", 280, 300,nil , 20 )
recording:stopRecording( )
recording:stopTuner( )  
end


function playRecording ()
print( "Play back recording" )
findRecording = audio.loadSound( "recordings.wav" , system.DocumentsDirectory )
audio.play( findRecording)
proof3 = display.newText( "proof3", 400, 300,nil , 20 )
end
```

*UPDATE: I've loaded an .wav file with actual sound into the system.DocumentsDirectory. Results: It works in corona simulator(hear sound), but it doesn't work on my phone (no sound). ***I believe the problem is that my phone can't access the files in system.DocumentsDirectory.

Following is my code that I've edited to test, and sample.wav is audio that has actual sound. Anyone have any insights?

```
function playRecording ()
print( "Play back recording" )
findRecording = audio.loadSound( "sample.wav" , system.DocumentsDirectory )
audio.play( findRecording)
proof3 = display.newText( "proof3", 400, 300,nil , 20 )

end
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you should be checking:

- RECORD_AUDIO permission in config file
- IsRecording is true after start and before stop
- size of sound file created
- if file created, copy it to your PC and see if it plays anything

Update:

If you know for a fact that all are true i.e. you have a sound file, then here are more questions to check:

- maybe the playback is not finding the file.
- Is it working in simulator?
- You able to hear any sound from other (non corona) games or apps on device?
- You able to hear sound when you play one of the corona demo apps that have sound, on your device?

Update 2:

If all the above pass, then "I believe the problem is that my phone can't access the files in system.DocumentsDirectory" is not likely true, unless there are config settings in the demo app that are different in your app like some config permissions.

Copy the Corona example that works to a new project and start adding code from your app. Test often as you might eventually add some app code that causes it to no longer work then you'll see what was wrong in your original app, or you'll end up having everything you need in your modified/extended app and you'll never know what was problem but you can then drop original source you have been working on.

Comment: Update checks: - I'm able to hear song in corona simulator, i'm able to hear sound from non corona games or apps, and i'm able to hear sound when I play corona demo recorder app. I can't hear sound on my app =(

Comment: @user3251969 Updated based on your latest checks.